# Is there a way to change the email of my first commit?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the author of a commit in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git)

I have push 5 commits but I want to change the author email adress I have push on the first commit.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, use `git filter-branch --env-filter`. The author and email are environment variables, just use the appropriate command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [git filter-branch](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-filter-branch.html)

You gotta decide for yourself if it's really worth the effort..

```
git filter-branch -f --commit-filter '
  if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "wrongemail@adress.com" ];
  then
    GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Firstname NAME";
    GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="email@adress.com";
    git commit-tree "$@";
  else
    git commit-tree "$@";
  fi' HEAD
```